# Is it possible to make a .js or .bat or .vbs file and make it email something when ran?

Tags: javascript, batch-file, vbscript

I need to be emailed every time my node.js or .bat file is opened. I've searched for so long, and found no up-to-date working solutions. Or do you know of any other ways I can be notified every time my app/file is opened? Please let me know!

Comment: Just use nodemailer.

Comment: How is this different from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72131890/how-to-send-an-email-from-a-node-js-application-or-bat-file)?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming, opening file means running your nodejs file on command line or on browser. I think you can are write one php script that can send email & call that PHP script using ajax every time when your node js file is run.